# kafka producer example - class not found exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm trying to run the kafka producer example as described on the kafka docs ([found here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example)).

However, when I try to run the producer I get a class not found exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/producer/ProducerConfig
        at com.t4g.app.RandomProducer.main(TestProducer.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.producer.ProducerConfig

Here is my dependency file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.1.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run the code using your pom.xml.
Are you able to see ProducerConfig class in Maven dependencies?

Try a clean build or delete the existing Kafka package [kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.jar] from Maven repository, update project to download the package again and see if it works for you.

Comment: @yamspog, hello, any updates on your problem ? Did you find a solution ? I am following the same tutorial, and I'm having a hard time setting everything up. If you could write an answer with detailed steps to get that producer compile and run, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @myna - I am using eclipse for compilation, I verified my code compiles and runs on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu platform, please provide additional details on what all you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add the following in your pom.xml. It will fix your issue.